# Stop creating core dump files after Linux's fork and kill

Tags: c++, linux, fork, kill

I have the C++ function shown below which works, but it creates a core dump file in Linux.  Is there a way to stop it creating core dump files?

PS: "version.out" hangs sometimes, so I am creating a new process and killing it after 1 second to avoid the program hanging and taking the output from /tmp/version later.

```
void bVersion(void)
 {
     pid_t pid;
     pid=fork();
     if (pid == 0)
     {
         system("version.out > /tmp/version");
     }
     else
     {
         // wait for 1 second
         sleep(1);
         kill(pid, SIGTERM);
         mverDir("/tmp/qnbversion");
         system("rm /tmp/qnbversion");
     }
 }
```

Comment: It would be useful to get backtrace in gdb for your corefile. SIGTERM does not create a corefile.

Comment: Note that your current code is not resilient in the face of multiple copies running at the same time.  Fixed names, especially in directories like `/tmp`, are a liability.  It would be a good idea to check the status of some of the operations you are trying, too.

Comment: You should investigate which program is dumping core. Try first `file core` (it should give you which program dumped that core). Then, assuming it is `version.out`, run `gdb version.out core` (and type `bt` and learn how to use `gdb`). A core dump is a *symptom* of something bad!

Comment: we use a Linux enabled target which does not have the complete Linux functionality but a stripped out version of Linux, it don't have gdb in it, and I cannot install it too, so is there any other way to call "version.out" from my c++ code without fork-ing a new process? and kill "version.out" if it hangs?

Answer (score 2):

The `setrlimit` function can be used to prevent core dumps when called with with the `RLIMIT_CORE` flag and limit values set to zero.